# Github API list sourced repositories

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

Is there any way to list the sourced repositories only?
I'm only able to get the whole list of repositories for a user which includes any forked repository, which usually returns a much bigger list than what I would like to.

This is what I'm using:

```
 https://api.github.com/users/alvarotrigo/repos?per_page=100
```

[The documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) doesn't seem to provide any filter parameter to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`search` api](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) to pass that kind of parameters (*the `fork` parameter is by default false*)

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:alvarotrigo
```

If you want to get the forks as well you would do

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:alvarotrigo+fork:true
```